# What is the difference between "ins" and "im" in German?

Tags: difference, preposition, grammatical-case

What's the difference between *ins* and *im*? They both translate to *in the*. I'm thinking *ins* is more a reference to place but I'm not sure when to use *im*.

Comment: ins = in das, siehe https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ins # im = in dem, siehe https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/im

Answer (score 14):

**im** is short for *in dem* and is used with dative case for masculine and neuter singular nouns. (The feminine singular equivalent would be "in der", plural would be "in den".) *im* is often (but not only) used to specify a location (*Wo?*/Where?). For example: *Ich schlafe im Hotel.* (I sleep in the hotel.)

**ins** is short for *in das* and is used with accusative case for neuter singular nouns. (The masculine sing. equivalent would be "in den", feminine sing. would be "in die", plural would be "in die"). *ins* is used together with verbs of motion to specify a destination, and could be translated as "into" in English, for example: "Ich gehe ins Hotel."

Comment: Exactly, case is the keyword here.

Answer (score 4):

The German preposition **in** can mean **in** or **into** in English

in + accusative means *into*

in + dative means *in*

*ins* is a contraction of *in das*, and *im* a contraction of *in dem*, so we have:

> ins Haus (=in das Haus) - into the house

and

> im Haus (=in dem Haus) - in the house

For those prepositions that can take either the accusative or dative, the accusative case is usually used where there is a sense of movement or change of state, and the dative in a static sense